# In Python is it possible to access method that is defined inside a nother method?

Tags: python, methods, nested

In the program bellow, is it possible to access method `AA` by only calling method `B`? Perhaps something similar to declearing variables global?

```
def A():
    print("This is method A.")
    def AA():
        print("This is method AA, which is inside method A.")

def B():
    print("This is method B.")
    AA()

B()
```

Comment: if you were to use nested function inside A, do the same inside B too. Otherwise just definite it outside like other function.

Answer (score 0):

A function defined within a function is by its nature not accessible globally. This is normally only done when you want encapsulation or if the outer function is generating and returning an inner function (like a factory function). If you need access to that function you can either return it as the result of function A, call function A and add a call to function AA within A, or define AA outside of A.